# how to route to dashboard after validation in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes

how  to validate user input before redirect to dashboard.i have given codes below,

below code working fine its loading dashboard first but in need to display login page. then after validation its should redirect to dashboard page.

please refer below link and download project i am using this template for my project but they are not given login validation.
https://www.creative-tim.com/product/black-dashboard

// app.vue

```
      <template>
        <div>
          <notifications></notifications>
          <router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
        </div>
      </template>

      <script>
        export default {
          methods: {
            disableRTL() {
              if (!this.$rtl.isRTL) {
                this.$rtl.disableRTL();
              }
            },
            toggleNavOpen() {
              let root = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
              root.classList.toggle('nav-open');
            }
          },
          mounted() {
            this.$watch('$route', this.disableRTL, { immediate: true });
            this.$watch('$sidebar.showSidebar', this.toggleNavOpen)

        }
        };
      </script>

      <style lang="scss"></style>
```

//route.js

```
      import DashboardLayout from 
           "@/layout/dashboard/DashboardLayout.vue";
      import LoginComponent from "@/layout/dashboard/login.vue"
      import NotFound from "@/pages/NotFoundPage.vue";

      // Admin pages
      const Dashboard = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "dashboard" 
        */"@/pages/Dashboard.vue");
      const pole = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "common" */ 
      "@/pages/Poles.vue");


      const routes = [
        {
      path: "/",
          component: DashboardLayout,
          redirect: "/dashboard",
          children: [
            {
              path: "dashboard",
              name: "dashboard",
              component: Dashboard
            },
            {
              path: "Poles",
              name: "Poles",
              component: pole
            } 
          ]
        },
        { path: "*", component: NotFound },
      ];
     export default routes;
```

//login.vue

```
       <template>
         <div class="login-wrapper border border-light">
           <div  class="form-signin">
        <h2  >Please sign in</h2>

        <input   type="text" name="username" v-model="input.username" 
              placeholder="Username"  class="form-control"   required 
                  autofocus>

        <input  type="password" name="password" v-model="input.password" 
             placeholder="Password"  class="form-control"   required>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"v- 
                  on:click="login()">Login</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'login',
        data() {
            return {
                input: {
                    username: "",
                    password: ""
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            login() {
                if(this.input.username != "" && this.input.password != 
                         "") {
                    if(this.input.username == "admin"  && 
                    this.input.password =="admin") {

                      this.$router.push('DashboardLayout');  
                    } else {
                        alert("The username and / or password is 
                    incorrect");
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("A username and password must be 
                 present");
                }
            }
        }
    };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

router.push expects a path so

```
this.$router.push('dashboard');
```

should do the trick

Comment: please download that template from link and check it bro